# Data classification based on plot

Tags: python, plot, classification

Python, matplotlib.pyplot

Trying to assign a colour to a graph node based on one of the node's values, I want to create a scale based on what comes up on the values' plot:

[image: Figure]

I'd want to divide it in these places:

[image: Figure_cut]

So there'd be 11 classes. How to make a 'cut' every time the plot 'jumps'?

Comment: Can you add sample of data

Comment: Just now I realised I plotted (y,x) instead of (x,y).
x: natural numbers from 1 to 64
y: [3976.25, 2356.25, 2134.0, 2130.0, 2055.0, 1949.5, 1923.0, 1630.0, 1373.5, 1356.0, 1169.5, 1154.0, 1062.0, 1031.5, 998.5, 981.0, 919.5, 879.5, 844.0, 770.5, 746.0, 665.0, 397.5, 382.5, 364.0, 330.0, 317.0, 311.5, 297.0, 196.5, 65.5, 64.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]